# How to disable up/down pan in UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to have my web view pannable left and right but not up and down.
Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the page in the uiwebview your own? In other words, can you set the    viewport on the page to the height you want for your uiwebview and remove scaling?  Then you would only be able to scroll left and right.

Comment: I will be creating the html, but I'm not sure what you mean by viewport on the page. At the moment I have a one-line piece of html in the web view and it is still pannable up and down.

Answer (score 0):

ok, well wrap your one line of html like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "height = device-height, user-scalable = no, width = WIDTH">
</head>
<body>
...YOUR HTML
</body>
</html>
```

Replace width with the width of your content, and see how it works.

Comment: I was assuming your uiwebview was full screen on the device, try replacing device-height with the height of your uiwebview